# How to use a trigger in SQL to update a row, based in two other rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Maybe it's too simple, but i'm having headaches on this task, i'm building a gym database for some homework that i have to calculate BMI based on other row named height and weight respectively. I don't know the approach to update this table, i've already tried

```
create or replace trigger calculate_BMI
after insert or update on evaluation
begin
    update evaluation
    set BMI = i.bmi, weight = weight(height*height)
    from inserted as i
end
```

and that's what i found

```
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'BJ111237.CALCULATE_BMI' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

it's not working, i'd appreciate if someone take me to some content to learn how to do this properly, cuz i'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard BMI calculation and your values are stored using the appropriate units, then the Oracle syntax for an update would be:

```
create or replace trigger calculate_BMI
before insert or update on evaluation
for each row
begin
    :new.bmi := :new.weight / (:new.height * :new.height);
end;
```

This is a "before" trigger.  It simply sets the new value doing a calculation.  No update is needed, because you want to change a column value in the same row of the same table being updated.

[Here](https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler) is a rextester showing it in action.

Comment: ```create or replace trigger calculate_bmi
before insert or update on evaluation
begin
    :new.bmi = :new.weight/ (:new.height*:new.height);
end;
```
I tried this, but returned 
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: @GabrieRabelo . . . The trigger needs `for each row`.  I also fixed a typo and added an example of it working.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your code:

- a trigger cannot action the table it was fired on; you do want a `before` trigger that sets `bmi` instead of an `after` trigger that attempts to update table `evaluation`
- your trigger should fire on a row by row basis instead of at statement level (so it needs the `for each row` option)
- pseudo-table `inserted` does not exist in Oracle; instead, you can use `:new.` to access the values that were passed for update or insert

You probably want:

```
create or replace trigger calculate_bmi
after insert or update on evaluation
for each row
begin
    :new.bmi := :new.weight / (:new.height * :new.height);
end
```

Comment: I've tried this: 
```
create or replace trigger calculate_bmi
before insert or update on evaluation
for each row
begin
    :new.bmi = :new.weight / (:new.height * :new.height);
end
```
But it's not working also, it's returning 

Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; indicator 
Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     ) , * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and or    || year day

Comment: @GabrieRabelo: sorry it has to be `:new.bmi :=` instead of `set :new.bmi =`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need specify if you want to change the new value that updated now, or the old value.

For example:

```
set new.BMI = i.bmi, weight = new.weight(height*height)
```